# Dungeons and Dragons Character Sheet generator using Python

Tags: list, dictionary

For fun I'm trying to create a character generator sheet for Dungeons and Dragons. I've got the program to randomly roll for my strength, charisma etc.

Now I want to be able to ask the user, "What type of weapon do you want to use?" `Get_Weapon_Choice`, then pull up a list of that weapon type. I've tried creating a list `weapon_Choices = ['Bow', 'Sword', ]`. Then I created 2 other lists, `bow = ['short', 'long', 'crossbow']` and `swords = ['short', 'long']` I know how to get input from the user, but I don't know how to take that input and print the list, I'm printing the variable name.

`chooseWeapon = input('What type of weapon would you like? Bow or Sword?')`

How do I use `chooseWeapon` to compare to `weapon_Choices` to make sure they didn't enter something like Spells, then use `chooseWeapon` to print either the `bow[]` list or the `swords[]` list?

Do I need to use MySQL along with Python? and create tables and then search the tables instead of lists?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a dictionary:

```
weapons = {"bow": ['short', 'long', 'crossbow'], "sword": ['short', 'long']}
# prompt user and convert to lowercase (our dict consists of lowercase strings)
chooseWeapon = input('What type of weapon would you like? Bow or Sword?').lower()
if chooseWeapon in weapons: # checks if the input is one of the keys in our dict
    print(f'Available {chooseWeapon}s: {weapons[chooseWeapon]}')
```

Comment: Thanks Abe!
I have never seen a dictionary setup this way before. I didn't know you could do that. I thought a dictionary had one key and one value. I'll experiment with it.
Thanks for an idea to try, I had run out of ideas,

Comment: @Donald_Smith you are welcome :) You can mark your problem as solved by clicking the tick next to my answer